# Fwrite PHP - How to output full loop to file?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, fopen, fwrite

I have created a script that's working great, but I want to take it to the next level and create a file for this information automatically. The problem is that when I add my looped elements to using fwrite, it only writes the first entry to the file.

Sample code:

```
$totallines=count($lines);
$i=0;
foreach($lines as $line) {
$i=$i;

$trimmed = trim($line);

$linesgetdomain = explode('/',$trimmed);
$domain = $linesgetdomain[2];
$qmark = "?";
$front301qmark = "Front Part ";
$end301qmark = " End Part";
$lastpartqmark = "Last Part $domain";

if (strpos($trimmed,$qmark) !== false) {

strstr($trimmed, '?');
echo $front301qmark;
echo substr(strstr($trimmed, '?'), strlen('?'));
echo $end301qmark;
echo "<br>";
echo $lastpartqmark;
echo "<br>";

} else {
```

What I tried  (placing this before } else {):

```
$fpqmark = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fpqmark, $front301qmark);
fwrite($fpqmark, substr(strstr($trimmed, '?'), strlen('?')));
fwrite($fpqmark, $end301qmark);
fwrite($fpqmark, PHP_EOL);
fwrite($fpqmark, $lastpartqmark);
fwrite($fpqmark, PHP_EOL);
fclose($fpqmark);
```

How can I write the entire loop to a file instead of just the first line? The output displays properly in normal format, but not when writing to a file.

Apologizes beforehand if this is a basic question. I'm new to PHP and my understandings of certain concepts are a bit vague. Sort of surprised I even managed to get this script to work. (This is only a small part of it, but if I can learn how to do this, I should be able to do the rest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using write,

```
$fpqmark = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
```

Use apend,

```
$fpqmark = fopen('test.txt', 'a');
```

The it will resolve your problem.

Comment: You are a life saver my friend! Thank you for helping a newbie out with the quick response! I will accept your answer when it allows me.

Comment: @Joe if it is the right answer I suggest you make it the accepted answer. I'm glad you found the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Yes, I did @Ggg, but I had to wait 10 minutes before doing so. It's done now. Thanks again!